# Variable axis in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, charts

I'm looking to create an assessment process in Excel with a ROI (Return on investment) graph as one of the outputs. The ROI term will vary for different projects, possibly 15 years, possibly 20, possibly 30 for example. I have an inputs tab where the project term (in years) is entered and I was wondering if this input value can be used to automatically determine the number of years on the x axis on the output graph?

Thanks

Comment: yeah you can use named ranges for axis and chart values, google dynamic chart

Answer (score 1):

Through VBA, it is possible to [change the X-axis minimum and maximum values](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/axis-maximumscale-property-excel).

**Example**

```
Dim TermLength

'Assumes the project term length is stored in cell A1 on Sheet1
TermLength = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value

With Charts("Chart1").Axes(xlCategory) 
 .MaximumScale = .MinimumScale + TermLength 
End With
```